# converting null values with pivot

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to convert NULL values in my script I am also using the PIVOT function. This is my script and my attempt to convert NULL to "0"

declare @custnum nvarchar(7) = '   1124'
declare @yr smallint = 2016

```
SELECT 'Customer Orders Returned' as Description, *
FROM (
SELECT left(datename(month,r.rma_date),3) AS RetMonth, 
ISNULL(COUNT(r.rma_num),0) as OrdersReturned
FROM dbo.rma r
WHERE r.cust_num = @custnum AND YEAR(r.rma_date) = @yr
GROUP BY left(datename(month,r.rma_date),3),r.rma_num
)
AS R

PIVOT
(
SUM(OrdersReturned)
FOR RetMonth
IN (Jan,Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec)
)AS pvt
```

My result:

[image: Results Table]

Would appreciate any suggestions to help resolve my issue.

Thanks!

Comment: To do this first you need to remove " * " from select and use the real column name, then Use ISNULL(columnname,0) in your query EXAMPLE:- select ISNULL(columnname,0) from tablename

Comment: Yet another example of why using * is a bad habit. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone. I tried select ISNULL(columnname,0) and it still did not work. However, I did find a solution on the site that did work:                                                                             COALESCE(Jan,0) Jan, COALESCE(Feb,0),....and so on for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Use ISNULL() Function

```
Select ISNULL(columnname,0) from tablename
```